# QR code printer/reader?

Tags: printing, qr-code

I run a small business repairing computers.  Sometimes I have very similar looking computers, and shenanigans ensue if the customer labels fall off or the serial numbers I record become detached from the computer in the course of repair.

Is there an app I can use to print a qr code of plain text information about a computer/client/problem?  I believe my current printer is equipped with bluetooth, but I wouldn't be appalled if I needed to purchase a specialized printer (zebra, or whatever).

Comment: Ideally the app would also read said qr codes, but a separate reader is also not the end of the world as long as it is a common and compatible qr form.

Comment: Technically speaking, your question is off-topic (see our [help-center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *Can you suggest an app that does X?*). Basically, any QR Code generator should be able to create such a code, and there are printing apps as well. So it should work creating the image, and "share" it with some printer app. Take a look at [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr) for a good example QR reader/creator.

Comment: If the customer labels / serial numbers can become detached, how do you ensure that your printed QR codes do not also become detached?

Answer (score 0):

Check out an app in the Play store called 'Barcode Generator / Reader'.

And here's a link on how to use it: [LINK](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-QR-Codes-with-an-Android-Phone)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of generating and printing QR code from your android phone directly.

https://github.com/msayanece/PrintQR

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since this isn't a programming site, a link to some source code with no APK file isn't going to help out our visitors a lot.